# Multiplying records in SQL based on combinations of two columns

Tags: sql

I know that title's a little bit vague.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a table with two particular rows, some_id and some_string.

```
some_id     some_string
4           'a'
7           'j'
12          'ee'
```

I would like to create entries for all combinations of these two columns, so that I end up with:

```
some_id    some_string
4          'a'
4          'j'
4          'ee'
7          'a'
7          'j'
7          'ee'
12         'a'
12         'j'
12         'ee'
```

How would I approach this? I happen to be using Postgres, but I can understand general instructions.

Comment: This term for this is a _cartesian product_, or cross-join. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select from both of them:

```
SELECT t1.some_id, t2.some_string
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

This will combine every value from `t1` with every value from `t2` resulting in a total amount of records equal to multiplying the total amount of records in both tables. You should add an `ORDER BY` clause if you want to order by `t1.some_id` as it is in your example

Comment: Great! Much simpler than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
select distinct s.some_id, s2.some_string
from yourtable s, yourtable s2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f585/1)

Comment: There's no need for `distinct`

Comment: @Ramblin'Man Not only there is no need of it but it also will result in records being filtered, which is not what the OP is expecting

Comment: @Ramblin'Man -- Perhaps, however, depending on the actual data and the expected results, `distinct` might be needed.  Consider duplicated results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6160e/2.  Really depends on OP needs.  Just trying to push in the right direction :D